# ModuleNotFoundError when running child package module

Tags: python, connexion

```
proj
|
|
|---flaskr
|    |---__init__.py
|
|    |---scripts
|        |---__init__.py
|        |---build_database.py
```

My `flaskr.__init__.py` looks like this

```
import os
import connexion
from flask_cors import CORS


def create_app(test_config=None):
...
```

When I run build_database.py in the project root folder with the following command

```
python3 -m flaskr.scripts.build_database
```

I get the following error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'connexion'
```

But I have installed `connexion` using pip and when I run the whole Flask app with `flask run` it works fine.

Any ideas why I'm getting the `ModuleNotFoundError` when running the `build_database` module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would run `python3 -mconnexion` to make sure python3 has access to the module.  I suspect flask and pip are running under a different python interpreter then python3.

Comment: Amazing, my python3 and pip are on different python versions, thanks!